# Changing tmux .bash_profile behavior

Tags: shell, login, tmux

I have a script in my .bash_profile that prompts for X sessions to boot.  When I launch tmux, I get this prompt that I had only intended for the TTY login.

Is there something I can put in .bash_profile that will simply run bash if it is part of tmux?  That is, can I check with bash if .bash_profile is being read within tmux?

Comment: It appears that tmux starts login shells by default.  I am not sure if there is a reason for this, but if you want to make tmux start non-login shells instead you can add `set-option default-command bash` to your `.tmux.conf`.  (`.bash_profile` is only read by login shells; non-login shells ignore it).

Comment: I asked a similar question and was redirected here. @jw013 's comment gives an effective way of changing this weird behaviour of `tmux` from within `tmux` (rather than tinkering the `.*profile` files), but it requires a `-g` flag to be effective, as in `set -g default-command zsh`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

tmux sets an environment variable called `$TMUX`, which I believe holds the location of the socket it's using. Either way you can use it in your `.bash_profile` to test whether or not it is being called from within tmux.

```
if [ -z "$TMUX" ]; then
    # not in tmux, do non-tmux things
fi
```

Or

```
if [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
    # called inside tmux session, do tmux things
fi
```

Comment: One could arrive at such knowledge by comparing 'printenv' output.

Comment: Is there any downside to this? I'm of the opinion that tmux should not launch shells as login shells, and while I've read vigorous debate about it elsewhere, I still haven't seen a compelling reason for it. I'm going to use this `$TMUX` check in my profile if for no other reason than to reduce `$PATH` duplication, but is there any downside?

Answer (score 4):

I usually use `$TERM` to test that. `screen` and `tmux` set it to "screen" by default.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `TMUX`, you can `export` your own. It is useful in the case there are more than one `tmux` users and you want to `source` it only for yourself.

Add the following line to `~/.tmux.conf`.

```
if-shell shell-command export SOMEONE_USING_TMUX=1
```

And, add the following lines to `~/.bash_profile`.

```
if [[ ! -z "$SOMEONE_USING_TMUX" ]]; then
    # source for yourself
fi
```