# How to prevent tmux from reading .profile/.zprofile/.bash_profile

Tags: zsh, tmux

**The original question**

Is it possible to override `tmux`'s default behaviour of executing `.[z|bash_]profile` files on every new session, window and pane?

In other words, I'd like it to only execute only the relevant `.[zsh|bash]rc` script, i.e. for the new session/window/pane to behave like an `xterm` or `urxvt`, not like a `tty`.

**More specifically (edit)**

I'd like to avoid changing anything to my `.*profile` and `.*rc` scripts. I'm looking for a way to ask `tmux` to open non-login shells in its new sessions, windows and panes by properly configuring it in `.tmux.conf`, in order to keep the prior philosophy of putting only actual 'login' instructions on `.*profile` scripts, as recommended for instance here: [What should/shouldn't go in .zshenv, .zshrc, .zlogin, .zprofile, .zlogout?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71253/what-should-shouldnt-go-in-zshenv-zshrc-zlogin-zprofile-zlogout)

I am aware on how to circumvent the issue by hacking e.g. `.zprofile` as was answered to [Changing tmux .bash_profile behavior](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61719/changing-tmux-bash-profile-behavior) , but the question is of how to do it from `.tmux.conf`

**Secondary question**

Why does `tmux` load the `.*profile` scripts by default, on **every** session, window and pane, whereas subshells on any context and all (or at least most) variants of X terminals don't?

**Some background information (not necessarily relevant)**

I barely started using `tmux` (only occasionally, for now), but I do have an ever-evolving setup, using `zsh` as my shell of choice, in which `.zprofile` expects to be called from a `tty` and do relevant stuff (like deciding to run `startx` or not based on whether it's on a laptop and the tty number), the `.zshrc` script expects to be called from any interactive environment and the `.zshenv` script expects to be loaded whether on an interactive environment or not.

**EDIT: Solution (based on comments below)**

Adding the following line to `.tmux.conf` overrides `tmux`'s behaviour and defaults to starting non-login interactive shells (zsh in this case) on new 
sessions, windows and panes:

```
set-option -g default-command zsh
```

Comment: Tmux does not read your `.bash_profile`, it's the shell that reads it.

Comment: @Marco : then why do the shells within new tmux sessions, windows and panes behave like login shells, whereas the shells inside a new xterm don't and other subshells don't?

Comment: regarding duplicate question : I did find http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61719/changing-tmux-bash-profile-behavior while searching before, but I don't want to test for tmux from within my .*profile scripts, but rather to change something on .tmux.conf so that shells in tmux don't read those scripts. Will edit question accordingly.

Comment: See [jw013's comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61719/changing-tmux-bash-profile-behavior#comment87813_61719)...

Comment: `.zshrc` is evaluated in interactive login and non-logins shells. To only evaluate code in login shells use `.zlogin` and to change  the tmux behaviour to use non-login shells use `set-option -g default-command 'zsh'`.

Comment: @jasonwryan I somehow missed that comment - and in fact it doesn't work as is, sadly, but Marco's variant in the comment above does exactly what I was looking for (the -g is fundamental, apparently - I'll add it to the original comment).

Comment: @Marco Your last comment actually solved my problem perfectly. Thanks a lot! And sorry for the (mostly) duplicate question...

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help. And it's good to be persistent and update the original question if the duplicate doesn't actually solve it. Sometimes questions get closed too quickly. But it's still better to improve existing answers than to scatter the information over several questions if they are closely related.