# New tmux sessions do not source bashrc file

Tags: bash, tmux

## Summary

When I create a new tmux session, my prompt pulls from a default bash configuration and I have to manually run `source ~/.bashrc` for my customized prompt.

## Analysis

I am using a RHEL 7 machine. I began noticing this behavior after a bash update a while back, but haven't gotten around to asking the question until now (and am not sure which update this began happening around).

For example, I've customized my prompt to look like:

`[user@hostname ~]$`

Whenever I start a new tmux session, it uses what appears to be the bash default:

`-sh-4.2$`

A quick run of `source ~/.bashrc` always fixes the issue, but it's annoying that I have to do this every time I want to fix something small. Any ideas on how to get tmux to do this automatically again?

If any more information is needed, I am happy to provide.

## tmux.conf

For reference, I have my `tmux.conf` file below, although it is hardly what you could call custom.

```
setw -g mode-keys vi

# reload tmux.conf
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message " ✱ ~/.tmux.conf is reloaded"
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As far as I know, by default `tmux` runs a login shell. When `bash` is invoked as an interactive login shell, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`. So you have to put `source ~/.bashrc` in one of those files.

Another way to solve this issue is to put in your file `.tmux.conf` the line:

```
set-option -g default-shell "/bin/bash"
```

Comment: I added the `source ~/.bashrc` line to my `.bash_profile`, tried logging out and back in, create a new tmux session, but no change. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to put in your file `.tmux.conf` the line `set-option -g default-shell "/bin/bash"`. This should solve your issue (at least I hope so)!

Comment: After reloading my tmux configuration, this solved my issue! Want to modify your answer or create a new one? I would be happy to mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: You're kind, I quickly modified my answer!

Comment: Note for macOS users: if you've installed `bash` via Homebrew and this doesn't work, change `"/bin/bash"` to `"/usr/local/bin/bash"`.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I have the same issue (bashrc not getting sourced on new tmux windows/sessions). `/bin/bash` is set as `default-shell` as displayed when running `tmux show-options -g`. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 55):

This is related to the Bash init files. By default, `~/.bashrc` is used in an **interactive, non-login** shell. It won't be sourced in a login shell. Tmux uses a **login shell** by default. Hence, shells started by tmux skip `~/.bashrc`.

> `default-command` shell-command
>
> The default is an empty string, **which instructs tmux to create a login shell** using the value of the `default-shell` option.

Init files for Bash,

1. login mode:

   1. `/etc/profile`
   2. `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` (only first one that exists)
2. **interactive** **non-login**:

   1. `/etc/bash.bashrc` (some Linux; not on Mac OS X)
   2. `~/.bashrc`
3. non-interactive:

   1. source file in `$BASH_ENV`

[image]

#### Solution

The weird interactive, non-login loading requirement confuses people in other situations as well. The **best solution** is to change the loading requirement of `~/.bashrc` as **interactive only**, which is exactly what some distros, like Ubuntu, are doing.

```
# write content below into ~/.profile, or ~/.bash_profile

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

This should be the solution you desire. And I recommend every Bash user setup this in the profile.

---

**Update**: the above settings is copied from Ubuntu. It seems they choose to load `.bashrc` in a login shell no matter it's within an interactive shell or not.

If you wanna detect an interactive shell, use `$PS1`.

```bsh
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" -a -n "$PS1" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

#### References

- [Unix Shell Initialization](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Unix-shell-initialization)
- [Shell startup scripts](https://blog.flowblok.id.au/2013-02/shell-startup-scripts.html)
- `man tmux`

Comment: This answer gave me the solution while the accepted one did not.

Comment: I would have liked more explanation about the proposed solution. It seems like that a non-interactive shell has no BASH_VERSION environment variable, and this is used to detect whether we are in an interactive or non-interactive shell. I have very little experience with such things. but it's weird that there is no dedicated way to test it.

Comment: @HorrorVacui `BASH_VERSION` doesn't ensure it's in an interactive shell, it only ensures it's in bash. Cause `.profile` is not used only by Bash. I just copied the content from Ubuntu. To detect an interactive shell, try `$PS1`.

Comment: After I added your stuff to my bash profile this break some Winscp commands, like duplicate files

Answer (score 13):

Adding the following to `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g default-shell "/bin/bash"
```

**DOES NOT** yield the desired result.

Only when adding `source "$HOME/.bashrc"` to `~/.bash_profile` the intended result is achieved.

This will work on an active tmux session when opening a new window or pane, and also when detaching and opening a new tmux session.

Tested on:

```
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
tmux 2.1
```

Comment: I wonder what are the downsides of the proposed solution. There is a reason why bash uses different files and sourcing bash_rc unconditionally goes against that reason.

Answer (score 4):

The solutions sourcing `~/.bashrc` via `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile`), including the top answer, work great.

An alternative that also works for me with Ubuntu 20.04/tmux 3.0a is adding this to `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g default-command bash
```

This alternative also solves another annoying tmux issue: doubling up on prepends to `$PATH` found in `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`. ([post I got the idea from](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/548516/486263))

Answer (score 3):

Modify your `$HOME/.tmux.conf` file with the following:

```
set-option -g default-shell "/usr/bin/bash"
set-option -g default-command bash
```

That should cover it. While you are at it, why not put the dotfile in the `$HOME/.config/tmux` folder where it belongs without the dot. And, add color output and a reload key binding to `$HOME/.config/tmux/tmux.conf`:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen256color"

bind r source-file "${HOME}/.config/tmux/tmux.conf"
```

If `tmux -V` < 3.1, add an alias to `$HOME/.bashrc` to load the config file from this location:

```
alias tmux="tmux -f ${HOME}/.config/tmux/tmux.conf"
```

Or make it a system-wide config at `/etc/tmux.conf`, the default location.

Comment: I think `screen256color` should be hyphenated: `screen-256color``. [FAQ](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-a-256-colour-terminal).

Answer (score 2):

[Andres Salgado's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/539537/390383) worked for me. Just to add to it.

I had this issue when working on Ubuntu 20.04.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Firstly, create a file called `.tmux` in the home directory of your machine, which is `~/.tmux.conf`.

Next, put in the configuration that you want to use for **Tmux** inside it and save it. For me the configuration I needed was the same as the **GNU screen** package that comes default with Ubuntu uses, so I copied the content of the `~/.bashrc` file into the `~/.tmux.conf` file. This way if I have to edit any of the configurations for **Tmux**, I wouldn't tamper with the one for the **GNU screen**.

**Note**: You could skip this step and just use the `~/.bashrc` file if you do not care for separation of concerns.

Next, add the file to either the `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` file. It should be added at the bottom of the file:

```
source "$HOME/.tmux.conf"
```

OR

```
source "$HOME/.bashrc"
```

Here's an example:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

source "$HOME/.tmux.conf"
```

**Note**: The `~/.bash_profile` file takes the first precedence, then the `~/.bash_login` file as the second precedence, and then the `~/.profile` file as the last precedence.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: According to your example, if you add `source "$HOME/.bashrc"` to the end of `~/.profile`, a login shell will source `~/.bashrc` twice.